# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'madataset_iter'

Tags: python, unsupervised-learning

My question is about **K-means clustering algorithm**, I keep getting the error *`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'madataset_iter'`* **{it was sorted out after correcting the typo error}** when I try to visualize the clusters after fitting my dataset into the model. Below   my code:

```
##Fitting kmeans to the dataset with k=4
km4=KMeans(n_clusters=4,init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
y_means = km4.fit_predict(dataset)

#Visualizing the clusters for k=4
plt.scatter(dataset[y_means==0,0],dataset[y_means==0,1],s=50, c='purple',label='Cluster1')
plt.scatter(dataset[y_means==1,0],dataset[y_means==1,1],s=50, c='blue',label='Cluster2')
plt.scatter(dataset[y_means==2,0],dataset[y_means==2,1],s=50, c='green',label='Cluster3')
plt.scatter(dataset[y_means==3,0],dataset[y_means==3,1],s=50, c='cyan',label='Cluster4')
plt.scatter(km4.cluster_centers_[:,0], km4.cluster_centers_[:,1],s=200,marker='s', c='red', 
alpha=0.7, label='Centroids')
plt.title('Customer segments')
plt.xlabel('Annual income of customer')
plt.ylabel('Annual spend from customer on site')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The new error i am getting is

'TypeError: '(array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 
  False,'

Comment: The error message seems somewhat self explanatory. You're passing `madataset_iter=300` as an argument, but `KMeans` doesn't expect that. Perhaps its a misspelling of `max_iter` or something?

Comment: Its 'max_iter' i didn't realize that, if after reading K-means documentation. Thanks for pointing it out. Moreover, I am still getting a 'TypeError', although I am reading the sklearn again, kindly point out the errors if you find any.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the KMeans constructor `__init()__` does not have a `madataset_iter` argument. Is there a typo? Should it be `metadataset_iter` instead?

Otherwise you should check the KMeans function documentation or code. There is no import statement in the code example provided, so we can not look it up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that. The correct argument there is 'max_iter', I made a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the KMeans from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html), the constructor for this object does not accept any argument called `madataset_iter`. The other named argument you are using do appear in the documentation I linked to, so it remains unclear where you got that argument name from.